# Ubuntu 14.04 just reboots on "install Ubuntu" (Intel DB85FL)

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, intel

I created an Ubuntu 14.04 DVD and tried to install ubuntu but it gets to the installation screen. If I click "install to Hard Disk" it immediately just reboots.

I've tried various BIOS settings with no luck.

I have an Intel DB85FL with i5 CPU and 8GIG Ram.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating another DVD? Or use an USB! :!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the DVD. Try using any other device like pendrive, etc.

Burn the iso to a pendrive or another DVD but this time keep the speed of burning to least possible value.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer!

Comment: But I told him a solution that might work. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the BIOS, the latest is [FLB8510H.86A](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23833&ProdId=3683&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09&DownloadType=BIOS) which was released on 2014/04/24.